# Understanding why an input is accepted by parser

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

For input `abb` answer is accepted but why?

Input `ab` right answer

Input `aab` rejected right answer

Input `aabb` accepted right answer

```
// parser file 
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}

%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'

%%
A:  S  { printf("accepted\n"); exit(1);}
    | error 
         |
        ;
S :  'a' S 'b'
      | 'a' 'b'
       |  
 ;
%%
void yyerror(char *s)
{
  printf("%s",s);
  exit(1);
}
int main()
{
 yyparse();
 return 1;
}   

// lex file
%option noyywrap
%{
#include "first.tab.h"
%}
%%

[a-b] {yylval=(atoi(yytext));
      return *yytext;}
\+|\-|\/|\* {return *yytext;}
. { yyerror("Invalid Character");}
\n { return 1;}
%%
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is why the parser accepts the input **abb**, when the grammar seems to describe an input with first a number of **a**'s, and then an equal number of **b**'s?

The Bison-generated parser doesn't have to parse *all* the input, just enough that it matches the grammar. For example, **aaabbbcde** consists of three **a**'s, followed by an equal number of **b**'s, and then the parser is happy and prints "accepted". There is some garbage at the end (**cde**), but the parser has already finished, and doesn't care. So **abb** is accepted, since **ab** is a valid input.

**aab** on the other hand is not accepted, since it starts with two **a**'s, but then the parser only finds one **b**.

You also have a shift/reduce conflict and a reduce/reduce conflict in your grammar, meaning that the same input can sometimes be parsed in more than one way. This complicates things further, and you should fix those conflicts.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. If i want to make abb should not be accepted. what should i do

Comment: Check for the end of input. That is, don't let your parser look for **a b**, but **a b DONE**.